# Error "Kernel reset" in Azure ML compute JupyterLab

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I first crated and activated a custom environment:

```
conda create --name my_env
conda activate my_env
```

Then I installed pip and ipykernel (with `conda install ...`). Finally, I created a kernel:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name my_env --display name "Python (my_env)"
```

When I switch to a Jupyter notebook, the new kernel is now available in addition to the already existing ones (Python 3.8 - AzureML etc.). However, when I select it, I receive the following error message: "Kernel reset. The kernel you tried to switch to was invalid or could not be launched. Your notebook has reconnected to your previous kernel."

I would appreciate help understanding/solving the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can check set of commands below to create kernel:

```py
CONDA_ENV_NAME = 'testenv'
KERNEL_DISPLAY_NAME = 'testkernel'

%conda create -n {CONDA_ENV_NAME} -y

%conda install -n {CONDA_ENV_NAME} ipykernel -y

!/anaconda/envs/{CONDA_ENV_NAME}/bin/python -m ipykernel install --user --name {CONDA_ENV_NAME} --display-name "{KERNEL_DISPLAY_NAME}"
```

Once the above code is executed in the juypter notebook, you need to restart the compute instance.
[image]